# Disabling a row in tableviewer in eclipse e4

Tags: java, eclipse, jface, e4

In my tableviewer, the user can check/uncheck items. I want to disable the rows that are irrelevant for a particular selection of objects, so that the user is not able to modify these rows. It seems pretty basic, but I am having a lot of difficulty in dooing the same. Please help!

Comment: sohw us some mo' meat(codez)

Answer (score 1):

Table / TableViewer does not support disabling rows.

You could clear unwanted selections in the selection changed listener (or check state change listener).

If your label provider implements `IColorProvder` you can change the foreground / background color of disabled rows.

Comment: I am using CellEditingsupport for the checkbox table viewer. I am confused where exactly should I implement IColorProvider.

Answer (score 0):

The rows may not be disabled, but if you do not want the users to modify the values of the row that could be achieved using the `EditingSupport` in JFace.
The `canEdit()` method in EditingSupport class determines if the cell can be edited.

eg.,

```
class MyEditingSupport extends EditingSupport {
...
@Override
protected boolean canEdit(Object element) {
    return condition_to_determine_if_the_row_should_be_disabled;
}
...
```

}

[Here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJFaceTableAdvanced/article.html#jfacetable_editor) is a good article on using EditingSupport for tables.

Comment: This will disable the entire column and not the row